# Using a conditional conditional in python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have a python function that contains an if-statement to check something.

```
def my_func(a, b, c):
  if a < b and b < c:
    #do complicated stuff
```

I want to modify the function so that the caller can determine whether or not to perform the if-statement check, by passing in a boolean.

```
def my_func(a, b, c, perform_check=True):
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make the conditional only be invoked sometimes, or skipped other times.

Comment: Maybe you could be more concise and just focus on the generic version of your problem.

Comment: The problem could definitely be distilled down to a more generic form, which would really help both the asker and the rest of us to figure out the root of the issue.

Comment: Sorry! I tend to get comments that my questions don't have enough info so I was trying to be verbose.

Comment: Heavily modified the question to make it more generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess something like this is what you need:

```
if include_already_seen or not data[person].get(item, 0):
```

Comment: Ahh, that's it. I need to spend some time brushing up on my boolean logic. [http://codingbat.com/python/Logic-2](http://codingbat.com/python/Logic-2)

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_recommendations(person, using=pearson_correlation, data=critics, include_already_seen=True):
  totals  = {}
  sim_sum = {}

  for critic in critics:
    if critic != person:
      similarity_score = using(data, person, critic)
      print "the similarity score between %s and %s is %d" % (person, critic, similarity_score)
      if similarity_score <= 0: continue    # ignore similarity_scores below 0

      for item in data[critic]:

        if include_already_seen or (item not in data[person] or data[person][item] == 0):
          totals.setdefault(item,0)
          totals[item] += data[critic][item] * similarity_score

          sim_sum.setdefault(item,0)
          sim_sum[item] += similarity_score

  #create the normalized list
  rankings = [ (total/sim_sum[item],item) for item, total in totals.items()]

  rankings_sorted = sorted(rankings)
  rankings_sorted.reverse()
  return rankings_sorted
```